# Display a column instead of a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have a table that is order "by column" instead of row ( one identity is one column, and each row is a caracteristic of the identity). like this :

- N° :............1...........2
- Name :....Peter...Michal
- Age : ........20.........23

I'm using the tool Datatable to search in the table, like [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). It worked BUT I would like to **display a column instead of a row** after searching for something.

For example, when i search 'Satou' [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) , i would like to see the column "Name" because Airi Satou belong to the column "Name" ( instead of seeing the row for the Name/ Position/Office/etc. )

I'm really stuck, i really appreciate some helps, thank you :)

Comment: "Jackson" might be both a name and an office. Then what?

Comment: Then I would like to see both columns, Name and Office, if possible. 
If not possible, it is OK in my case to say : each cell is unique on my array

Comment: How about [iterating over the columns](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()) and [searching each one in turn](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())?